# MySQL: Adding X minutes to a time column

Tags: mysql

I have a column with a time and a column with an integer representing minutes. Now I want to add/substract the minutes from the time column. The following works but feels weird (CURTIME here as time column and 15 as int column):

```
SELECT ADDTIME(CURTIME(), CONCAT("00:" , 15, ":00")) AS foo FROM dual;
```

How can this be improved?

Comment: You want to edit the values in your table or just to get the time updated, without changing the original value?

Comment: Actually I want to use that in a WHERE clause... I have events which can require some additional time before and after the event and the length of this time is stored in the DB in that integer field.

Comment: If you can provide a MWE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can provide a more specific answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `INTERVAL` with `CURTIME()` or `CURRENT_TIME()` or similar:

```
SELECT CURTIME() + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
```

As in:

```
mysql> SELECT CURTIME() + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE;
+--------------------------------+
| CURTIME() + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE |
+--------------------------------+
| 12:23:24                       |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

For your case, if your `CURTIME()` field is a `TIME`, and the duration is an integer, then they should just slot in ok, e.g.:

```
SELECT time_field + INTERVAL my_duration MINUTE
```

If not then you could use `CAST()` to get the types right for the addition.

> Date arithmetic also can be performed using INTERVAL together with the
>   + or - operator:
>
> ```
> date + INTERVAL expr unit
> date - INTERVAL expr unit
> ```
>
> INTERVAL expr unit
>   is permitted on either side of the + operator if the expression on the
>   other side is a date or datetime value. For the - operator, INTERVAL
>   expr unit is permitted only on the right side, because it makes no
>   sense to subtract a date or datetime value from an interval.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I really like your response! Now I am stuck with MySQL 5.5... On 5.5, I get NULL as result. Need to upgrade soon. Thanks!

Comment: I think this should work in earlier versions including 5.5. It might just be a types issue or similar if it's not working on 5.5.